# how to prevent flutter showBottomSheet from being dismissed by dragging down?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using showBottomSheet in flutter to show a persistent bottom sheet. how can I prevent flutter showBottomSheet from being dismissed by dragging down?
  I have added my code below. you can place a rawmaterialbutton and with onpressed call this function.

```
  void itemChooser(
      {int currentItemCount, String name, callBack, BuildContext context}) {
    int chosen = 0;
    showBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
              height: 500,
              color: Colors.white,
              );
        });
  }
```

Comment: I am unable to find `showBottonSheet` widget. Please can you add a link to its docs.

Comment: @MangaldeepPannu https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ScaffoldState/showBottomSheet.html

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: @MangaldeepPannu I have added my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `enableDrag` property of `BottomSheet` to `false` its `true` by default

```
BottomSheet(
  enableDrag: false,
  builder: //builder
),
```

Refer [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomSheet-class.html) for more info on `BottomSheet`

Comment: thanks but I am using shoBottomSheet widget and it does not have this property

Answer (score 5):

Just wrap your child with `GestureDetector` and set  `onVerticalDragStart: (_) {}`,

```js
showBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => GestureDetector(
    child: *your_widget*,
    onVerticalDragStart: (_) {},
  ),
 
);
```

Comment: Exists any chance that I can toggle the possibility to dismiss the BottomSheet?

Answer (score 4):

If you use `showModalBottomSheet`, simply use `enableDrag` property:

```dart
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => yourWidget,
  enableDrag: false,
);
```